# Jquery click is not working on dynamically added table tr via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I am getting data from my database and displaying it on my HTML via php echo. Now I need to put a click function on specific tr with id `breakrow`, but this click function is not working. I am using `.on` function as suggested in documentation for dynamically added content. Also I dont see any error in console also.
Here is the sample code. (When I add same code directly into html page, its working as expected)

PHP Part:

```
echo '<div class="container" id="container">
        <table class="gridtable" id="tableMain">
            <thead>
                <tr class="tableheader">
                  <th>customer</th>
                  <th>product</th>
                  <th>thedate</th>
                  <th>value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="breakrow"><td>customer 01</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                <tr class="datarow"><td>customer 01</td><td>product 01</td><td>30 10 2017</td><td>974.57</td></tr>
                <tr class="datarow"><td>customer 01</td><td>product 02</td><td>04 12 2017</td><td>634.50</td></tr>
                <tr class="datarow"><td>customer 01</td><td>product 03</td><td>30 10 2017</td><td>974.57</td></tr>
                <tr class="datarow"><td>customer 01</td><td>product 04</td><td>04 12 2017</td><td>634.50</td></tr>

                <tr class="breakrow"><td>customer 02</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                <tr class="datarow"><td>customer 02</td><td>product 01</td><td>04 12 2017</td><td>634.50</td></tr>
                <tr class="datarow"><td>customer 02</td><td>product 02</td><td>30 10 2017</td><td>974.57</td></tr>


                <tr class="breakrow"><td>customer 03</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                <tr class="datarow"><td>customer 03</td><td>product 01</td><td>30 10 2017</td><td>974.57</td></tr>
                <tr class="datarow"><td>customer 03</td><td>product 02</td><td>04 12 2017</td><td>634.50</td></tr>
                <tr class="datarow"><td>customer 03</td><td>product 03</td><td>30 10 2017</td><td>974.57</td></tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>';
```

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#tableMain').on('click', 'tr.breakrow',function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.breakrow').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

can someone guide me how to resolve this ?

Comment: _Suggetsion:_ Don't output large chunks of HTML using echo. End the PHP block using `?>`, write your HTML and then astart the PHP-block again, if needed, using `<?php`. That way, you won't need to care about escaping quotes and your IDE will be able to syntax highlight the HTML properly, making it _way_ easier to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When loading content using ajax the script needs to bind the dynamically added content so you can use below script which can take effect on dynamically loaded data.

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr.breakrow', function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.breakrow').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Comment: : Thanks, its working

Comment: @acr You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

your click function is not working because **jQuery is running on client side** and **php is running on server side** so when the script executed it will not find the particular ID because the table is rendering via php.

This is done by event delegation. Event will bind on wrapper-class element but will be delegated to selector-class element. This is how it works.

```
$('.wrapper-class').on("click", '.selector-class', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

**Note:**
wrapper-class element can be anything ex. document, body or your wrapper. Wrapper should already exist.

Answer (score 1):

**When adding the dynamic content or add other elements after the window loaded or any ajax data, In this condition static click `$(element).click(function(){})` is't work, You must bind the target element with document, Here the example**:

```
$(document).on('click', 'your target element', function(){
    //your code here......
});
```

_ - - - - - - _

**Thank you**

_ - - - - - - _

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass second argument on click event.working code is as per below.Here i just alert on click,you have to put your custom code in place of alert.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#tableMain tr.breakrow').on('click',function(){
       alert('toggle');
     });
});
```

Click [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/spLewmd0/) for working example in jsfiddle.